# Powershell restore database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Trying to get a script put together that will run and search a location for the most recent database file and restore that to an SQL Server.  I have the search function working well but I am unable to get it to restore the database.

```
import-module sqlps
#update path for to actual backup location
$path = "D:\Temp"
$logPath = "D:\Log" #change to proper log path when running
$backupPath = "D:\backup" # shouldn't need but putting here just encase
$server = "server1"
$database = 'DBname'
#$database = gc( 'C:\Database Recovery Script\'+$server+' Database list.txt' )
#$dataFileLocation = "D:\SqlData\$data.mdf"
$password = 'xxxxxxx'

foreach ($data in $database)
{
#For testing use the QBW filter
#Once testing is over swithc to proper filter.
$filter = '*server1_DBname_FULLL*'
#$filter = '*_'+$Server+'_'+$data+'_FULL*'
$latest = get-childitem -Path $path -Filter $filter |
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
    Select-Object -first 3
$latest.fullname


$dataFileLocation = "D:\SqlData\$data.mdf"
$logFileLocation = "L:\SqlLogs\$data.ldf"

$sql = @"
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE "$data" `
FROM DISK = N'$latest.fullname' `
WITH FILE = 1, `
     MOVE N'CurrentDB' TO N'$dataFileLocation', `
     MOVE N'CurrentDB_log' TO N'$logFileLocation', `
     NOUNLOAD, NORECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 5, PASSWORD = '$password' ` `
"@

 invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "localhost\tedbdev01" -Query $sql -Username "xxxx" -Password "xxxx"
}
```

When I run the script I get a error that it cannot open backup device. When I run just the script in SQL Server admin center I get

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   The media family on device 'D:\Temp\20191020_045728_AWSCSQL02_DB21387_FULL.sqb'
>   is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

If anyone can give me ideas at what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: `$latest` is an array of up to 3 objects according to your code. Remove `Select-Object -first 3`. Also I would remove the backticks from the here string and use `FROM DISK = N'$($latest.fullname)'` to make sure the variable expands properly. In short examine `$sql` before your call. That is what I noticed at first glance.

Comment: Why don't you use the [```restore-database```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/restore-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet sqlps provides?

Comment: `.sqb`. Was your backup taken with SQL Backup from RedGate? If so, it's not a native SQL backup and so you won't be able to restore it with native restore.

Comment: It was taken with redgate.  Everything i looked at on there website said you can use native sql.  Do you happen to know what i need to do to fix.

I also tried to use the restore database and that only works if the database already exists on the server.  At least from what i looked at. I want this to work regardless of a database existing or not.

Comment: You'd have to use [Redgate's own tool](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sbu10/scripting-sql-backup-pro) to script the restore. The syntax it uses looks very much like T-SQL, but is not actually T-SQL. If installed as an extended stored procedure, it can be invoked from T-SQL.